# What is the better way to set an UIView backgroundColor to transparent?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I know you can set an UIView's backgroundColor to transparent as following:

```
UILabel *aLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
aLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

But according to some articles said, `[UIColor clearColor]` do not have good performance, so, what's the better way to set an UIView's backgroundColor to transparent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The *reason* `[UIColor clearColor]` is slow is because it is transparent. Anything you do that requires the system to calculate layer blending is going to be slower than opaque. If you need it to be transparent, use `[UIColor clearColor]`. If you can avoid it being transparent, then avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you can use NSString's drawAtPoint method in view's drawRect method, instead  UILabel.

```
NSString *text = @"hello world";
[text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10) forWidth:165 withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16] lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
```

Answer (score -2):

You can just set the background to any color with an alpha value of 0.0.

Comment: This will have the same performance as `[UIColor clearColor]`. "Clear" just means "transparent black."